# ADB Connection Error: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I did updated my studio to `1.5.1 in Linux Mint` and just launched my studio. Its giving me a dialog (while ADB Initializing) saying:

> - Unable to create Debug Bridge:
> - Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output:
> - /home/ajay/Developement/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/ajay/Developement/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Please provide a fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is adb executable? does it have executable permissions? try to run sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ajay/Developement/Sdk/

Comment: same problem, have you found any fix? running it from the terminal I get "cannot execute binary file"

Comment: Same problem after last update of platform-tools.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866

Comment: i had to download platform-tools again and my issue got resolved

Answer (score 17):

**Old Answer:**
I'm having the same problem (with ADB in Linux Mint 17, 32bit Quiana).  I made sure that the file ADB in platform-tools directory has executable permission but it appears that will not run at all (even if I try stopping Android Studio and running ADB on its own).  I tired uninstalling and re-installing the Android SDK Platform Tools (v 23.1) but that didn't help.  Is there a way to revert back to an earlier version of Platform Tools?

**Improved Answer:**
If you're using a 32-bit Linux system to run Android Studio and have had the misfortune to have updated to platform-tools 23.1.0 you need to revert back to platform-tools 23.0.1.

Here's how I did that:

Download the 23.0.1 files with this link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Move the downloaded zip file to the directory where your Android SDK is installed (something like ~/Android/Sdk).

Rename the existing directory containing the 64-bit files ( ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools to ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools-64-bit ).  Note: you could just delete these files but I saved them.  They don't take up much space.

From the ~/Android/Sdk directory unzip the downloaded zip file.  That should have created a new directory ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools containing the platform-tools 23.0.1 files and sub-directories that you need for your 32-bit system.  ADB should now work just like it did before this "update" broke it.  (Bad Google, Bad, Bad)

**Reference:**
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866

Answer (score 14):

Replacing old platform tools fixed my problem too.
Thanks "RealDogBoy".

Download the 23.0.1 files with this link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

1. I renamed the old "platform-tools" folder to platform-tools_23.1
2. unzipped the above zip file into the sdk folder.
3. restarted the Android Studio.

Started working fine.

Comment: But why we can't update to 23.1, it's known bug?

Comment: because Google decided to switch to 64-bit binaries in 23.1.0. So it doesn't work for users of 32-bit systems

Comment: Hope they will fix this bug

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows get into `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`
and delete the platform-tools folder, then restart android studio you will be prompted to download a new one. That worked for me :).

Answer (score 1):

i was working on this issue for the last three days .i am running a 32 bit linux mint on a hardware having intel i3 m350.i tried installing 64 bit ubuntu and then installed android studio in it..but that dint work..so the solution is this.
go to the link below and download
 https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
unzip it and place it in /Android/SDK/.and dont forget to delete the platform tools folder there.paste the freshly extracted download there . now restart your android studio and run the app on adb on a real device..it works..100%
note:i chose real device because im on a 32 bit machine and latest release of android studio doesnt support avd on 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

I just close my genymotion, and force close adb in Activity Monitor, and open my emulator again. Then, it works. (mac)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I downgraded my platform tools from 23.1 to 23.01 n everything works fine. My system is 32-bit it seems that probably the updated version only supports 64-bit systems.