# Unable to detect adb version, adb output Unable to obtain debug bridge

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I am new to coding and have recently installed the latest version of Android Studio and the SDK package on my Mac OSX.  I am receiving the error in the title when trying to run the basic "HelloWorld!" app.  I know many have commented on this error, and I have tried putting earlier versions of the ADB file into my platform-tools folder but it did not fix the issue. I think it is because I am running it on OSX. As it is now, I have the adb execute file in my platform-tools folder in the right location, so I'm not sure why I am still having issues. Thanks so much.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? what does `adb devices` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue like E.Do: running Android Studio 1.5.1 on Mac OSX 10.6.8. 
`Unable to detect adb version, adb output:` appears in the bottom left corner of Studio.
When tried to run the app, Studio is crashing. 
`ADB not responding. If you like to retry, then manually kill "adb" and click "Restart"` However, when tried to do that from Terminal, it throws this:

```
./adb kill-server
Illegal instruction
```

A similar issue was reported here but for Ubuntu 32bit (new SDK platform tools is 64bit) [ADB Connection Error: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236449/adb-connection-error-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server)
And it was solved by unpacking and putting platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip which is 32bit into sdk/platform-tools folder (of course you need to move/delete current data from folder).
Same file could be downloaded for OSX as well from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-macosx.zip, but when doing the same thing, Studio keep crashing with above mentioned error.
In Android Studio's SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools 23.0.1 is listed so all should work but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was previously running Yosemite and recently upgraded to El Capitan and I am no longer receiving the error message when I try to run my application in the simulator.