# error running app, unable to obtain debug bridge; Unable to detect adb version

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've come across different variations of this question in a search for an answer but I still can't figure it out and it's driving me insane. 
I've built my app in android studio v.1.5. My problem is when I go to 'run' the app, I get errors saying:

> error running app, unable to obtain debug bridge

along with the message:

> Unable to detect adb version, adb output

I'm running it on a Mac OSX 10.7.5

If anyone could give me a detailed description of what to do in layman's terms I'd be so grateful (only learning!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB Connection Error: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236449/adb-connection-error-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server)

Comment: How about you upgrade Android Studio? And macOS while you are at it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run your app in your smartphone, make sure that the developer options and the USB debugging is enabled

To turn on the USB debugging just go to settings > about phone > build no.(Tap seven times).
Then you will see the developer options. Go there and enable the USB debugging. That's It

Answer (score 0):

Check your ADB integration is checked or not if not then check it.

**Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration.**